# telerik winforms equivalent of combobox dropdownstyle=simple

Tags: winforms, drop-down-menu, telerik

When using telerik winforms dropdownlist, the dropdownstyle have only 2 options, ie, dropdown and dropdownlist. But in visualstudio combobox has one more style option, ie, dropdownstlye="simple".

How can we achieve the "simple" style option in telerik winforms dropdownlist.

Please advice.
Thanks
Jim

Comment: I am now sure if there is a difference between RadDropDownList's DropDown style and the Simple style of a ComboBox. What is the previse behavior you are looking for?

Comment: When using radDropDownList, the list will expand only when we click on it. But in Visual studio ComboBox with simple style, it shows expanded combobox, by default. I want that expansion by default (without clicking on it) in RadDropDownList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such functionality available out of the box, however, using RadTextBox and RadListControl you can easily achieve it. Just align them properly one beneath the other on the form and use the following events: 
**RadListControl.SelectedIndexChanged** - use to set the text of the text box, when item in the control is selected
**RadTextBox.KeyDown** - when enter is pressed, find an item with the entered text and if such exists, select it
**RadTextBox.TextChanged** - clear the selected item in the list control

Here is also a snippet.

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        AddTextBox();
        AddListControl();

        radListControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += radListControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        radTextBox1.KeyDown += radTextBox1_KeyDown;
        radTextBox1.TextChanged += radTextBox1_TextChanged;
    }

    void radTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radListControl1.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    void radTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            radListControl1.SelectedItem = radListControl1.FindItemExact(radTextBox1.Text, false);
        }
    }

    void radListControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Position > -1)
        {
            radTextBox1.Text = radListControl1.Items[e.Position].Text;
        }
    }
```